# `List' is not a template

Tags: c++, templates

Does anyone have any insight in to how this error occurs? I made a LinkedList a template in C++ and in my main method I have this code:

```
List<int> list;
list.insert(1, 9);
```

And I am getting this error on the first line:

`` `List' is not a template ``

I am including this file:

```
template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
       List();
       List(const List& aList);
       ~List();

       bool isEmpty() const;
       int getLength() const;
       void insert(int index, const T& newItem);
       void remove(int index);
       void retrieve(int index, T& dataItem) const;

private:
        struct ListNode
        {
               T item;
               ListNode *next;
        };

        int size;
        ListNode *head;

        ListNode *find(int index) const;
};
```

Not posting the implementation file for spacial reasons but I am post individual functions if necessary.

I tried changing `List(const List& aList);` to `List(const List<T>& aList);` but that didn't really change anything. Templating syntax confuses me >.<

Comment: Compiles fine for me when I mock the functions with empty bodies. The error must be somewhere else. Also, don't put template code in .cpp files, the compiler needs to know the exact code that needs to be instantiated, so it needs to be in a header.

Comment: It compiles fine for me (modulo the undefined functions at link time) using g++.

Comment: Do you have the implementation in a separate file from the header?

Comment: @Xeo: What do you mean don't put template code in .cpp files? Is something like this bad practice? http://pastebin.com/9xV42eUS

Comment: It's not bad practice, it is wrong. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: It's nice to find out that my textbook is feeding me false information.

Comment: The implementation of the template class methods must be available to the compiler at the instantiation point (where you use the template). The C++98 standard defines the `export` keyword for permitting separate compilation of template code, but it is not supported by the major compilers and is deprecated in the upcoming C++0x standard. So you have to include the implementation of the template in the header.

Comment: @Guelgosh: Take one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). :)

Comment: @Xeo: Sadly I am using a required class text and doing one of the problems from the book.

Comment: `I made a LinkedList a template`.  No you didn't.

Comment: If your header implementation is in a separate file, include it at the bottom of your header.

Comment: I think everybody is missing the point. Split declaration from implementation must give *linker* errors, not compiler errors. Could you please post the full error messages so we can investigate if this error is not due to any previous error?

Comment: @Xeo: No, it's bad practice. The compiler doesn't give a crap about headers/source files. It sees the same stuff. It's just a real nightmare to make linking work properly when you put template definitions in source files, because _conventionally_ we do not include such code in all TUs independently. So putting template definitions in headers **should** definitely be done, but it's not strictly an outright error not to. (And, notably, if you only use the template in one TU, you'll have no problems whatsoever!)

Answer (score 2):

In my projects I declare list like this to avoid the error

```
    using namespace std;
    #include <list>
```

Comment: Maybe you should read this [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Using the standard library `std::list` doesn't answer this question.

Comment: I stand corrected about bad practice -But I was answering the original question. it should be #include <list> then in all uses std::list

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your List template class is not in a different namespace?

Have you tried renaming your template class to something unique to ensure you are instantiating the class you think you are?

Comment: This does not provide an answer, please comment instead

Comment: @GGO I beg to differ. It provides two possible explanations for what may be causing this error. I phrased them as questions on purpose (7 years ago) because it is not certain that either of these are in fact the reason for the OP's error.

Comment: Someone flag this answer like a low quality answer. I only moderated it. And it's right, today, your answer doesn't compliant : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
Sorry, but only SO Admin can decide now

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible that you wrote the template code in the .cpp file?

I'm going of by this line:

```
Not posting the implementation file
```

Template code can only ever be in the .h file, there can be no "implementation file".
The reasons are as complicated, as they are silly :)

Comment: This isn’t the reason. This answer has already been posted – and deleted – here. However, this error is unrelated.